# Lombok not working with Eclipse Neon 2 on macOS Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos-sierra, lombok

Am using Eclipse Neon 2 on macOS Sierra and Lombok 1.16.14.

When I ran the Lombok Installer, it could not find any of my Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA installations.

So, I had to manually "Specify Location" by pointing to the following file (no other directory or file would enable the "Install" button to become clickable):

```
eclipse-standard-neon2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

After, installing, it said that "Installation was completed" and inside the eclipse.ini file, it had the following line inserted for the last line ( I pasted the full contents of the eclipse.ini ):

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

lombok.jar was also automatically placed inside the same directory as eclipse.ini:

```
eclipse-standard-neon2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/
```

However, when I launch Eclipse Neon 2 and trying to use any of the Lombok annotations, its fails to recognize the library in its classpath, even if I declare package import explicitly.

Also, when I re-run the Lombok Installer (in order, to uninstall Lombok), it still can't find the previous Eclipse IDE that I had to manually specify from the previous install?

When I tried to run Eclipse from the command line using the following (it still didn't work and there were no errors listed in stdout):

```
eclipse-standard-neon2/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS$ ./eclipse -vmargs -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

Here's the stdout from running it from stdout:

```
objc[52949]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib (0x100543480) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1005a54e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
671 2.4.8.xx-201702132212-e46 = STARTING
672 2.3.11.xx-201702132212-e46 = STARTING
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /Users/devuser/DevTools/Java/eclipse/eclipse-standard-neon2/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.7.0.20160603-1933.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://462.fwk1881585646:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://462.fwk1881585646:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Guess, I am not going to have the privilege of using / learning Lombok anytime soon. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if Lombok is installed correctly by opening the `Help` 🢒 `About Eclipse` dialog from the menu. In the white area on the right, the bottom line should read: `Lombok v1.16.14 "Candid Duck" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/`

If it doesn't, please verify your `eclipse.ini`. Make sure that the line `-javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar` is below `-vmargs`. You can try using a full path here, it might be resolved from the wrong location.

If the line is there, but the lombok line is not display in the dialog, try to start Eclipse from the command line, and see if you get error messages.

The next version of lombok should find this installation.

The reason why the uninstaller doesn't suggest the previously entered location is that the lombok installer doesn't try to remember anything. The upside is that directory moves don't interfere, and the lombok installer doesn't leave any traces on your computer.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: If someone could explain how I can have <nobr> in stackoverflow messages (around -javaagent:lombok.jar in this post), I would appreciate that. I'd rather not replace the - by &x#2011; ('NON-BREAKING HYPHEN' ) because that would break the installation of people that would copy-paste the code.

Comment: Hi Roel, I just updated my question (see above) by providing the entire listing of eclipse.ini and yes, it is under -vmargs. Inside About Eclipse / Installation Details, Lombok doesn't exist. I also added the full directory path to lombok.jar and it still doesn't work. This is sad because I have other versions of Eclipse and IntelliJ and the Installer could not detect any of them. Why didn't the Lombok team just make plugins for Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Hi Roel, I also added the stdout from running Eclipse from the command line in my original question (see above). Am disappointed that it doesn't work. :(

Comment: When is the next version going to be released?

Comment: The things Lombok does cannot be done by Eclipse plugins.

Comment: If we can figure out why Lombok doens't work on some MacOS Neon.2 installations and have a fix, we will ship a new version. We cannot reproduce the problem, it works on our Mac.

Comment: Roel, so you are saying that I'll just have to not use it and wait? I have older Eclipse installations in my computer along with IntelliJ IDEA. The installer could not even detect a single IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ) for the matter. Not trying to disrespect... With all due respect, all I am trying to do is report an "edge case". I'll give up on this issue and just go back to conventional Java coding. I think if I specify Lombok as a dependency in Maven or Gradle, it might work but its an overkill to the practice coding that I do. Sorry you can't figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136442/discussion-between-roel-spilker-and-socal-javaguy).